# Почему при открытии нового окна PlayingLayout(в функции start_game) оно сразу же закрывается?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class UiMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("Main Menu")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.bt1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bt1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 91, 31))
        self.bt1.setObjectName("bt1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.bt1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start game"))


class UiPlayingWindow(object):  # создание обьектов для игры
    def __init__(self):
        self.lees = []

    def setupUi(self, PlayingLayout):
        PlayingLayout.setObjectName("PlayingLayout")
        PlayingLayout.resize(1000, 1000)
        x = 10
        for i in range(10):
            # доавить рандом
            exec(f"self.le{i} = QLabel('this le{str(i)}', self)")
            exec(f'self.le{i}.move({x + i * 50}, 30)')
            exec(f'self.lees.append(self.le{i})')
        self.retranslateUi(PlayingLayout)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PlayingLayout)

    def retranslateUi(self, PlayingLayout):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PlayingLayout.setWindowTitle(_translate("PlayingLayout", "PlayingLayout"))


class PlayingLayout(QMainWindow, UiPlayingWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, UiMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.commands()

    def commands(self):
        self.bt1.clicked.connect(self.start_game)

    def start_game(self):
        # открыть новый layout
        pl = PlayingLayout()
        pl.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы создаете объект `pl` - как локальную переменную и она удаляктся сборщиком мусора. Продлите жизнь данного объекта, сделайте его атрибутом класса:

```
    self.pl = PlayingLayout()
    self.pl.show()
```